# Simple, very simple wait in js

Tags: javascript, wait, synchronous

I'm new here (but I know "copy-paster" ^^).
I recently started to create a BASIC type programming language, which I interpret with JS, lots of JS ^^. I managed to create the object system, variable etc ... and especially library made in js, but the problem is in the "input" function of the library "console", for that I add an input text in the "pre" which I use as a console, but the code continues to execute while the input is empty. What I want is simple, it's a stupid "wait conditiont" :

```js
var finish = false;

document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    var inputText = document.querySelector("#input").value;
    finish = true;
  }
}

wait if(!finish))

//continue
```

or more simple :

```js
//code

wait if(condition)

//continue after wait
```

cordially, Manolo

Comment: `it's a stupid "wait conditiont"` in a sync environment that pauses execution and waits for an async event that will only occur after all (waiting) sync code is executed. You might want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: finish is just a variable.  it is not an event that informs or emits when it changes.  wait if "finish" does not actually make sense, unless you have either a loop that checks for finish to change, or an event emitter or callback when an operation changes the finish variable.  The actual use case for "wait if" is a problem that Promise, async/await, callbacks, events are normally meant to solve, but you haven't given a clear description of what exactly is the problem you are actually solving.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you want to do once finished, you might as well just call a function instead of setting `finish` to true.

Other wise you will have to use a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async functions and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

An async function is a function that allows using the `await` keyword. The `await` keyword waits for a `Promise` to resolve so you then make function that returns a promise and resolves some value when you're ready to continue. That value will be returned to the `await` keyword.

```js
async function main() {
  log('enter your name:');
  const name = await getInput();
  log('Hello', name);
  log('How old are you?');
  const ageString = await getInput();
  const age = parseFloat(ageString);
  if (age > 55) {
    log('Hello Boomer!');
  } else if (age > 40) {
    log('Hello Gen-Xer!');
  } else if (age > 25) {
    log('Hello Millenial!');
  } else {
    log('Hello Zoomer!');
  }
}

main();

function getInput() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const elem = document.createElement('input');
    elem.type = 'text';
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.focus();

    function handleInput() {
      elem.removeEventListener('change', handleInput);
      elem.disabled = true;
      resolve(elem.value);
    }

    elem.addEventListener('change', handleInput);
  });
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = args.join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
input { display: block; }
```